# HTTPX RESPX Pytest TypeError: Invalid type for url. Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'tuple'>:

Tags: python, pytest, httpx

I have a function in my Python class that works fine when I use it in my other `.py` file.

```
@exception_handler
def get_all_workspaces(self) -> Union[WorkspacesModel, GSResponse]:
    Client = self.http_client
    responses = Client.get(f"workspaces")
    if responses.status_code == 200:
        return WorkspacesModel.parse_obj(responses.json())
    else:
        results = self.response_recognise(responses.status_code)
        return results
```

The Idea is `Client` already has a URL and then we add `workspaces` in that URL. It works fine when I'm trying to execute it in another Python file.

After creating a test for it

```
baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/"
    
def test_get_all_workspaces_validation(
    client: SyncGeoServerX, bad_workspaces_connection, respx_mock):
    respx_mock.get(f"{baseUrl}workspaces").mock(
        return_value=httpx.Response(404, json=bad_workspaces_connection)
    )
    response = client.get_all_workspaces()
    assert response.code == 404
```

It raises the following error

```
client = SyncGeoServerX(username='admin', password='geoserver', url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/')
bad_workspaces_connection = {'code': 502}, respx_mock = <respx.router.MockRouter object at 0x103fac550>

    def test_get_all_workspaces_validation(
        client: SyncGeoServerX, bad_workspaces_connection, respx_mock
    ):
        respx_mock.get(f"{baseUrl}workspaces").mock(
            return_value=httpx.Response(404, json=bad_workspaces_connection)
        )
>       response = client.get_all_workspaces()

test_gsx.py:34: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../src/geoserverx/_sync/gsx.py:97: in inner_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
../../src/geoserverx/_sync/gsx.py:109: in get_all_workspaces
    responses = Client.get(f"workspaces")
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1045: in get
    return self.request(
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:821: in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:908: in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:936: in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:973: in _send_handling_redirects
 response = self._send_single_request(request)
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1009: in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py:218: in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/respx/mocks.py:177: in mock
    request = cls.to_httpx_request(**kwargs)
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/respx/mocks.py:304: in to_httpx_request
    return httpx.Request(
/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_models.py:328: in __init__
    self.url = URL(url)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <[AttributeError("'URL' object has no attribute '_uri_reference'") raised in repr()] URL object at 0x10496ef10>
url = (b'http', b'127.0.0.1', 8080, b'/geoserver/rest/workspaces'), kwargs = {}

    def __init__(
        self, url: typing.Union["URL", str] = "", **kwargs: typing.Any
    ) -> None:
        if isinstance(url, str):
            try:
                self._uri_reference = rfc3986.iri_reference(url).encode()
            except rfc3986.exceptions.InvalidAuthority as exc:
                raise InvalidURL(message=str(exc)) from None
    
            if self.is_absolute_url:
                # We don't want to normalize relative URLs, since doing so
                # removes any leading `../` portion.
                self._uri_reference = self._uri_reference.normalize()
        elif isinstance(url, URL):
            self._uri_reference = url._uri_reference
        else:
>           raise TypeError(
                f"Invalid type for url.  Expected str or httpx.URL, got {type(url)}: {url!r}"
            )
E           TypeError: Invalid type for url.  Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'tuple'>: (b'http', b'127.0.0.1', 8080, b'/geoserver/rest/workspaces')

/Users/krishna/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/geoserverx-Yc0Bl2cH-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_urls.py:91: TypeError
```

Comment: What line of code actually raises that error?  Can you post the whole traceback error?

Comment: So, what exactly is `self.http_client`?  The implication here is that it was not set up properly, or it's not expecting to be used the way you are using it.

Comment: But the same functions works fine when I use it in my another py file .. 


from geoserverx._sync.gsx import GeoServerXAuth, SyncGeoServerX

client = SyncGeoServerX.from_auth(GeoServerXAuth("admin", "geoserver"))
response = client.get_all_workspaces().workspaces.workspace[0]

print(response)

Comment: I also ran into this Error with `httpx>=0.23.1` - workaround was to downgrade `httpx` to 0.23.0

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `httpx>=0.23.1` you will need **`respx>=0.20.1`** ([Changelog](https://github.com/lundberg/respx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0201---2022-11-18)) to resolve this error.